# Xcode 4.2 with ARC: will my code run even on iOS devices with firmware older than 5.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I updated my Xcode to 4.2 version, which includes the ARC technology. It seems to be a good thing, but if I enable ARC and edit my code according to Apple's suggestions, will my app build&run even on 4.3.x devices? Or only for iOS 5 ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ARC applications will run on OS 4.0 (4.3?) and up. On 4.3 you will lose the zeroing-weak-reference feature though. So if you rely on __weak, you shouldn't expect to work properly on < 5.0.

Comment: Just FYI my iPhone 3G (iOS 4.2.1) and iPad 1 (iOS 4.2) both ran several ARC apps just fine. Apple states that ARC is compatible with iOS 4 so I would expect it to work with 4.0. Minus the weak references of course.