# non ARC classes in an ARC compliant project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on an iPhone app which does some video processing, I had to include to classes that are not ARC compliant ( dealloc , releasing stuff ). So I manually went and made them arc compliant. 
Later on I discovered the compiler flag for any class that can make it non ARC in an ARC project `-fno-objc-arc`.

My question is, if I do flag those classes with the compiler flag, what are the reprecussions of this? performance hit? is it a good idea? my app iOS 5.0 and up. I couldn't find any resources that talk about pros and cons of doing this.

Comment: [Here is a pretty good description of ARC][1]; Its advantages and disadvantages.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888568/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-arc

Comment: Why don't you convert non-ARC files to ARC files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> If I do flag those classes with the compiler flag, what are the repercussions of this?

The only thing I believe you need to worry about is to make sure that the non-ARC library follows Cocoa naming conventions associated with memory management (e.g. only return objects with +1 `retainCount` if the name begins with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`). Otherwise your ARC won't be able properly manage the resulting object. Most well written classes will conform to this pattern, so you should be perfectly ok using the `fno-objc-arc` flag, but it depends entirely upon the class in question.

> [Is there a] performance hit?

There are no practical performance issues.

> [Is] it a good idea?

All things being equal, I generally like to convert the code to ARC. A couple of situations where I might refrain from converting:

- It is a library for which there is active development, and if I create my own personal ARC fork, I'll lose out on the future revisions of the library.
- The library is incredibly complex and/or has constructs that are not easily converted to ARC.

---

Bottom line, if I can convert to ARC, I will. Usually in this process, I'll do the necessary testing to make sure I'm comfortable with the library, that there are no leaks, etc., so it's a productive (if annoying) process to go through. We're all responsible for the code we include in our projects and I don't think one should ever integrate code without going through some due diligence that is a natural by-product of an ARC-conversion and testing process.

If I convert to ARC, I offer to contribute the conversion back to the original author (e.g. via a GitHub "pull request" or whatever mechanism the author is open to) so it can be integrated into the code base.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, there are no performance issues with using or disusing ARC. ARC is basically normal reference counting, it's just not the programmer who inserts the `release` calls, but the compiler.