# How backward compatible is ARC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, backwards-compatibility

Will an app compiled with ARC work on previous (<5.0) versions of iOS?

Comment: My god, a comment and answer saying it's not backwards compatible at all. Both are wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.2 with ARC: will my code run even on iOS devices with firmware older than 5.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768861/xcode-4-2-with-arc-will-my-code-run-even-on-ios-devices-with-firmware-older-tha)

Comment: @MikeWeller - I gave a talk on ARC a few months ago, and fully a quarter of the audience seemed to not realize that ARC was supported back to 4.0 and Snow Leopard. The messaging on this got really confused around WWDC last year.

Comment: @BradLarson: good to know. I had the impression that are not backward compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Comment: Just to add: use `__unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak` where you can't use it. Don't depend on these referenecens being nil'ed for you as they would be with the `weak` qualifier.